# Hypothesis test on the difference in proportions

Tags: r

I am trying to run code for "Hypothesis test on the difference in proportions" but "infer chain" fails to run >>> Error: Syunik(variable) is not a level of the explanatory variable.

```
RuternMigration <- read.csv ("ruternmigration.csv", header=TRUE)

RuternMigration 
str(RuternMigration) 

RuternMigration[, 'returnmigration'] <- as.factor(mtcars[, 'returnmigration'])
str(RuternMigration) 

p_hats <- RuternMigration %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(prop_favor = mean(returnmigration == "Yes")) %>%
  pull()

# Compute difference in proportions
d_hat <- diff(p_hats)




null <- RuternMigration %>%
  specify(returnmigration ~ region, success = "Yes") %>%
  hypothesize(null = "independence") %>%
  generate(reps = 500, type = "permute") %>%
  calculate(stat = "diff in props", order = c("Syunik", "Aragatsotn"))
```

Error: Syunik is not a level of the explanatory variable.

Comment: Please paste your error message in full, untouched.

Comment: actually, "Error: Syunik is not a level of the explanatory variable." this is a whole error message